# How to use SqlDataAdapter for update in local DB?

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter, local-database

I'm trying to update, but it does not work, no throwing exception, but it does not update,. I use local DB, I was helped [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.updatecommand?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlDataAdapter_UpdateCommand).

In the past I did update with oledb in MS Access. I tried also with oldb and did not work, maybe because local DB?

Thank you.

```cs
    try {

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Table1 SET WordsType = @wordsType WHERE ID = @id", cn_connetion);

    //SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(); //edited
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wordsType", wordsType);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
         
    if (cn_connetion.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        cn_connetion.Open();
    }

    //adapter.UpdateCommand = command; 
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

Comment: You don't need data adapter to run update command. You can just execute `command.ExecuteNonQuery()` to execute update command in database

Comment: Still not working, maybe there is a problem with the syntax?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Can you share the updated code in the original question?

Comment: I edited what I changed, but this is the update code .. not working I mean it does not update, and does not send an error , It does not go into catch..

Comment: No matter, my mistake, I sent the value
  existing for editing, and not the new one,
Sorry for the trouble mate.. thank you